# Approximating dates - Javascript/JSON

Tags: javascript, json, nvd3.js

I'm trying to visualize some data I have. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hohenheim/6R7mu/10/

For this visualization, I started a small subset of the JSON data I'm trying to visualize, `data2` which looks like

```
data2 = [
   {
      "startDate":1396263600.0,
      "adId":2483231759355,
      "endDate":1401101940.0,
      "impressions":754831
   },
   {
      "startDate":1393851600.0,
      "adId":2750329551133,
      "endDate":1404212340.0,
      "impressions":3947368
   }
];
```

Notice there is a date range in the data. My goal is to split the impressions uniformly into all the days in that date range and aggregate all the impressions per day over all ads. IE the final result will only have 2 attributes: `date` and `impressions`. I have a solution that SHOULD work but days are not aggregating properly because the millisecond representations of the days are not equal even though they may approximate to the same day. For example, 1398164400000 and 1398171600000 represent the same day but have different millisecond values.

Basically, if you examine the middle part of the region on the chart, notice there are oscillating values but really each pair of differing values should actually represent just 1 day summed together.

Is there any way to properly merge 2 millisecond versions of dates that approximate to the same day?

Comment: Subtracting (t % (24 * 3600 * 1000)) should do it.

Comment: @MikeSamuel if that's your answer, post it as an answer.

Comment: Mike - brilliant, that was what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most clocks that are used to produce timestamps don't include leap-seconds, so you can isolate the day part by subtracting

```
(t % (24     /* hours per day */
      * 3600 /* seconds per hour */
      * 1000 /* milliseconds per second */ ))
```

from the time-stamp `t`.

Even if the timestamp does include leap-seconds, that function will still give you a pretty good proxy for day-of comparison.  It just may get dodgy with timestamps that are close to midnight.

If you are in a time-zone that is far from the day boundary, you will probably want to adjust your timestamp to millis since the epoch in the local timezone, and just ignore DST which again will introduce some inaccuracy around midnight.